# Passing session or cookie variables to server tags in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, c#-4.0, cookies

This is probably a simple question but, it eludes me, I have a variable that I have set as a code-behind session in another page of an ASP.NET application. Let's say it is: `Session["UserName"]` and I want to pass it from a code behind page to the server tag. The server tag looks like this:

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDelta" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringAlpha %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ThingTitle], [ThingSynopsis], [ThingCategory], [ThingType], [ThingUserName] FROM [ThingOfSubmissions] WHERE ThingUsername = <%$ Session["UserName"] %>"`

I can't use: `<%$ Session["UserName"] %>` directly in the server tag as shown above without it generating an error about mal formed server tags. So my question is, how can I pass this session  variable or any other application variable (non SQL Server variable) into this bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...I had to set the value as a Session Parameter in the actual page not in the server-side code as follows:

```
  <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="UserName"
            SessionField="UserName"
            Type="String" />
```

Next, I used @UserName inside the page server tag code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the property in server-side code ?

```
SqlDataSourceDelta.SelectCommand = string.Format("SELECT [ThingTitle], 
[ThingSynopsis], [ThingCategory], 
[ThingType], [ThingUserName] 
FROM [ThingOfSubmissions] 
WHERE ThingUsername = '{0}'", Session["UserName"]);
```

Comment: I need it for a datagrid though.

Comment: What do you mean ? You can set DataGrid properties in server-side code too you know, including binding items. Can you post your complete code and markup so I can have a look ?

Comment: I was able to fix it using my method the way I had coded it. I know that you can accomplish it also they way you sent it. It was just the way that I had initially done it. I am learning exponentially :)